# Number of ways of distributing white and black balls into bowls

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

This is a self-answer question that repeats [this posted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4863413/balls-in-5-bowls) that the original poster deleted themself.  I regard the math problem as interesting enough to warrant posting.

I will be very interested to see if someone can post a more elegant approach than my *semi-brute-force* approach.

**The Problem**
I have 5 distinguishable bowls, 7 indistinguishable white balls and 8 indistinguishable black balls.  A white ball can be distinguished from a black ball.  In how many different ways can I distribute the white and black balls so that each bowl gets exactly $~3~$ balls.

**Interpretation**
I am assuming that the order that the 3 balls are placed in a specific bowl is irrelevant.  So, if a bowl has (for example) 2 white balls and 1 black ball, it is irrelevant whether the black ball was placed in the bowl first, second, or third.

**Note**
I attempted to search MathSE to determine if this was a duplicate question.  I couldn't find a question that reproduces a constraint similar to the constraint that each bowl gets exactly $~3~$ balls.

**Note**
I applied the tag of Combinatorics simply because I didn't know how else to tag the problem.

---

See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Equivalent Problem**

Isn't this simply solving for the number of integer solutions of

$$
x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}+x_{5}=7
$$

subject to $x_{i}\leq 3$? Here $x_{i}$ is the number of white balls in bowl $i$.

**Solution**

Because $4+4>7$, it's not possible to have more than one $x_{i}\geq 4$. Therefore, using stars and bars, then subtracting the case in which one bowl has more than three white balls:

$$
\binom{5+7-1}{5-1}-5\cdot\binom{5+3-1}{5-1}=155
$$

The same as OP's final result.

Comment: I agree, nice answer. +1.

Answer (score 0):

In the originally posted question, the original poster suggested that the answer is $~\displaystyle \binom{15}{7}.~$  This is reasonable, because there are $~15~$ positions that the $~7~$ white balls must be assigned to.  However, this approach is also wrong, because it wrongly presumes that the order that (for example) the white balls are placed in a bowl is relevant.

For example, if you label the bowl-1 positions as (1a), (1b), (1c), then the $~\displaystyle \binom{15}{7}~$ computation would **enumerate as distinct** (1a,1b,1c) = (white,black,black), (black,white,black), and (black,black,white).

My approach to this particular math problem, which **does not generalize well**, will be to categorize the various distributions based on an over-counting-denominator factor that I will assign to each distribution.

Any given distribution may be represented by the ordered 5-tuple $~(v,w,x,y,z),~$ where $~v,w,x,y,z \in \{0,1,2,3\},~$ and $~v + w + x + y + z = 7.~$  Here, $~v,w,x,y,z~$ represent the number of white balls assigned to each of bowl-1, bowl-2, ..., bowl-5, respectively.

For any distribution $~(v,w,x,y,z),~$ if $~k~$ is the count of how many of these 5 variables are in {$1,2$}, then the over-counting-denominator factor assigned to this distribution will be $~\dfrac{1}{3^k}.~$

Therefore, the entire problem reduces to identifying how many of the $~\displaystyle \binom{15}{7} = 6435~$ distributions have $~k = 0, ~k = 1, \cdots, k = ~5.~$

With respect to the problem's constraints, the $~7~$ white balls may be satisfactorily [partitioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) as:

- 3-3-1-0-0 
  This can happen in $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{2} \times \binom{3}{1} \times 3 = 90~$ ways. 
  The over-counting-denominator factor here is $~\dfrac{1}{3}.$ 
  The adjusted enumeration, for this bullet point is $~30.~$
- 3-2-2-0-0 
  This can happen in $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{2} \times 3^2 = 270~$ ways. 
  The over-counting-denominator factor here is $~\dfrac{1}{3^2}.$ 
  The adjusted enumeration, for this bullet point is $~30.~$
- 3-2-1-1-0 
  This can happen in $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{3}{2} \times 3^3 = 1620~$ ways. 
  The over-counting-denominator factor here is $~\dfrac{1}{3^3}.$ 
  The adjusted enumeration, for this bullet point is $~60.~$
- 3-1-1-1-1 
  This can happen in $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{1} \times 3^4 = 405~$ ways. 
  The over-counting-denominator factor here is $~\dfrac{1}{3^4}.$ 
  The adjusted enumeration, for this bullet point is $~5.~$
- 2-2-2-1-0 
  This can happen in $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{3} \times \binom{2}{1} \times 3^4 = 1620~$ ways. 
  The over-counting-denominator factor here is $~\dfrac{1}{3^4}.$ 
  The adjusted enumeration, for this bullet point is $~20.~$
- 2-2-1-1-1 
  This can happen in $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{2} \times 3^5 = 2430~$ ways. 
  The over-counting-denominator factor here is $~\dfrac{1}{3^5}.$ 
  The adjusted enumeration, for this bullet point is $~10.~$

**Sanity-Check**
$90 + 270 + 1620 + 405 + 1620 + 2430 = 6435.$

**Final Computation**
$30 + 30 + 60 + 5 + 20 + 10 = 155 ~$ different ways that the balls can be distributed.